# ProcessStartInfo waiting infinitely when hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, processstartinfo

Below code is working in `Console/Windows Application` also its working in web applications when I'm running the application through `Web Development Server`

```
  ProcessStartInfo gsProcessInfo;
  Process gsProcess;
  gsProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  gsProcessInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
  gsProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  gsProcessInfo.FileName = (string)filePath;
  gsProcessInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
  gsProcess = Process.Start(gsProcessInfo);
  gsProcess.WaitForExit(-1);
```

**Problem**

When I'm hosting my web application in IIS , the process is waiting infinitely.
I googled and found that the issue might be related to permissions and followed the solutions given there but no luck.

Following are the configurations of my hosted application

Application Pool

[image]

[image]

Guide me what else is required or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Have you checked if "MyPool" identity is not "ApplicationPoolIdentity" (default value)? If so, you should try to change the default identity with a user.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit..as how to do waht you are suggesting

Comment: Click on Test Settings and check if there are 2 green indicators if yes then you have permissions

Comment: @S.Petrosov yes its showing two green indicators...but still not working

Comment: Test Settings checks for the application path.. I'm guessing your problem it's related to "filePath". By the print screen provided I can see you're using "MyPool" so what I was suggesting to check is: go to ApplicationPools root, mouse right button on MyPool, Advanced Settings then check for Identity

Comment: @FrancescoMilani did what you suggested and updated my post with the image also..still no luck

Comment: What I suggested is that you need to change ApplicationPoolIdentity with a user with enough privileges.

Comment: @FrancescoMilani : did what you suggested MyPool->AdvanceSetting->Identity->Custom Account.. used the User who has admin privileges...still no luck